# Network programming with Python - TCP client/server

Tags: python, tcp, network-programming, client-server

I am currently learning about networking with Python and have created a simple TCP server and client. The client and server connect just fine, however,  when I run the client script and input something from the prompt I get a NameError exception for the input I entered. This shouldn't be the case as the input is supposed to be referenced by an identifier (*data*).

I've gone through the code but can't seem to find the issue. Please see both the client and server code below:

**Client script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import *
from time import ctime

HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpCliSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpCliSock.connect(ADDR)

while True:
    data = input('> ')
    if not data:break
    tcpCliSock.send(data)
    data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
    if not data:break
    print(data.decode('utf-8'))
tcpCliSock.close()
```

**Server script:**

```
from socket import *    
from time import ctime

HOST = ""
PORT = 21567
BUFSIZ = 1024
ADDR = (HOST, PORT)

tcpSerSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
tcpSerSock.bind(ADDR)
tcpSerSock.listen(5)

while True:
    print("waiting for a connection.....")
    tcpCliSock, addr= tcpSerSock.accept()
    print("....connected from:", addr)

    while True:
        data = tcpCliSock.recv(BUFSIZ)
        if not data:break
        tcpCliSock.send(bytes('[%s] %s' % (ctime(), 'utf-8'), data))
    tcpCliSock.close()
tcpSerSock.close()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Try data = raw_input('>') instead of input('>') in your client script..

Comment: Your code seems to be correct, so show the whole error msg or it's hard for us to find out whats wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) builtin you used in your client script evaluates the user's input as Python code (which is what generates the NameError). Use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead to simply get text input from the user.

Comment: From the `print`, `input` and `bytes` syntax it may be the user's example is for Python 3, but running it on Python 2 if getting `NameError`.  In Python 3, `raw_input` doesn't exist and `input` is correct.